# Speed up (vectorization?) bootci to get estimates by group?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, vectorization, confidence-interval

Given a bootstrapped sample of an investment strategy with n (weights), m(#bootstraps), and p(duration of investments), I want to calculate the sharpe ratio and the confidence interval for each weight (n) and duration (p).

Because I have several investment strategies I would like to run this code several times.

How can I speed up or vectorize the following code ? I have tried to split the matrix, and parallel computing but it still takes a long long long time to run for one sample. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
% set matrix dimensions
n = 60;
m = 1000000;
p = 3;
% create random 3D matrix (Bootstrapped Sample)
A = rand(n, m, p);
l_ci = 0.05; % set the alpha level for the confidence interval
nboot = 100; % set the number of bootstrap samples
% Preallocate matrices to store Sharpe ratios and confidence intervals
sharpe_ratios1 = zeros(n, p);
cis1u = zeros(n, p);
cis1l = zeros(n, p);
% Sharpe ratio bootfun
sr = @(x) mean(x) ./ std(x);
tic
for i = 1:n % Loop over the weights
    for j = 1:p % Loop over the horizons
        
        % Get the boostrap returns for the current weight and horizon
        yhat1 = A(i, :, j);% 
        % Calculate the CIs
        [ci_sr1, sr1] = bootci(nboot, {sr,yhat1'}, 'alpha', l_ci, 'Options',statset('UseParallel',true));
        % Store the Sharpe ratio and confidence intervals
        sharpe_ratios1(i,j) = mean(sr1);
        cis1u(i,j,:) = ci_sr1(2);
        cis1l(i,j,:) = ci_sr1(1);
    end
end
toc
```

duplicate question:https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1961609-speed-up-vectorized-bootci-to-get-estimates-by-groups?s_tid=prof_contriblnk

Comment: I don't have the right toolbox to use `bootci` and don't really know much about what it does, but you may be able to get a small speed-up by tweaking your Sharpe ratio bootfun. First, defining it as a full-fledged function and passing a handle to it may be slightly faster than the anonymous function you have. Second, you could remove some overhead by defining your function as: `function y=sr(x), n=length(x); mu=sum(x)/n; y=mu/sqrt(sum(abs(x-mu).^2)/(n-1)); end`. Note that you may lose some numerical precision compared to the native `mean` and `std` functions.

Comment: I find it faster, on large datasets, to first run bootstrp to get sample index, then run stats (mean, std, etc.) on a separate step. Not clear on the underlying reason through.